# Copy table with partitions using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Any idea how can I duplicate a big table with the partitions.

For example I have a table x with 1,000,000 row and 10 daily partitions I want to copy most of the data to a new table named y with the partition meta data.

is this possible?

Comment: you should clarify " ... most of the data ... "

Answer (score 1):

As far as duplicating the table, yes, it should be possible as stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#copying_partitioned_tables).

If you are using the CLI you could just run a `cp` command like:

```
bq cp dataset.old_partitioned_table dataset.new_partitioned_table
```

Or if using an API client just make sure to setup the [configuration.copy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.copy) properly when running a job resource.

You said in your question though that you want to "copy most of the data" so it looks like you want to have some sort of filter applied. One possibility could be duplicating the table and then running either some query or DML update to account for the changes you need.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, see above updated example

Comment: Maybe you didn't save your edit as the original question remains the same